# Wing Loading in a vertical loop

Tags: aerodynamics

I have been sent some old intermediate Royal Navy exam papers from 1956, I took a similar exam in 1966. One question concerns Wing Loading in a vertical loop, i,e, at the top and bottom. I know the weight, radius, speed (remains constant) and wing area. Units are British Imperial. In the deep recesses of my mind I remember that:

W=L= Clrv^s where r is density in straight and level flight.

Question

what other factors or formulae do I need produce an answer.

Comment: You may add a link to your exam paper. Note that you can also use write [math formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) in a clearer way.

Comment: Is your question "how to compute the wing load at the top and bottom of a vertical loop?"?

Comment: In a real aircraft, speed won't remain constant in a loop without a LOT of throttle & speedbrake inputs, which aren't typically (probably, *ever*) accomplished. G-loading will be related to the radius of the loop, so even assuming a constant speed (works well in Physics class), you'll need that term in there. Of course, a constant pull will give you x+1 G's at the bottom of the loop, but x-1 at the top.

Comment: Wing loading will stay constant or slowly decline as you burn off fuel, but load factor will vary throughout the loop. Depending on how it is flown, it can be negative at the top and 3 or 4 at the bottom when 1 ist the value for straight flight.

Comment: @Manu H:  "You may add a link to your exam paper."  It's paper.  How do you hyperlink to paper?!  ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall by scanning it, searching a copy somewhere,... Old exams can be published on examination records.

Comment: Manu H yes looking for the forula.

Comment: @PeterKämpf The wing loading should not stay constant in the loop due to the following. The wing loading is defined as the mass of an object divided by the area of the wings (assuming the weight is equal to the lift generated by the wings). At the bottom of the loop, the "apparent" mass would be increased due to the sum of the weight and centrifugal force. At the top of the loop, those two forces would have opposite directions, which means lower "apparent" mass and lower wing loading than at the bottom of the loop.